# Enabling VoiceOver in macOS Sierra using AppleScript is not working

Tags: macos, applescript, voiceover

I am trying to enable VoiceOver in macOS Sierra using AppleScript. I don't see any error, it is just not getting opened.

Here is the script I am using, which has worked well on all other version of macOS I have tried it on.

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to key code 96 using command down
```

Comment: Testing in **macOS Sierra** by manually pressing **⌘F5** does work and brings up the initial **VoiceOver** _dialog box_, however, the **AppleScript** _code_ in your question does not work in **macOS Sierra**,  while it does work testing in e.g. **macOS High Sierra** and  **macOS Catalina**.  I do not know why it is not working in **macOS Sierra** and am posting a comment for two reasons. **1.** To confirm it is not working programmatically  in **macOS Sierra**, yet manually it does. **2.** The other option is to try using **UI Scripting** and script enabling it from **System Preferences**.

Comment: @user3439894 so the alternative is to use UI Scripting only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is coded to assume that **VoiceOver** has never been turned on and that one does not want to see the standard *dialog box* that shows the first time **VoiceOver** is turned on, or again thereafter.

Note that this makes use of the single line of *code* presented in the other answer, which I do not consider a complete answer, however, without it the other option is **UI Scripting**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
try
    set doNotShowSplashScreen to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.VoiceOverTraining doNotShowSplashScreen") as integer as boolean
on error
    set doNotShowSplashScreen to false
end try
if doNotShowSplashScreen then
    do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/VoiceOver.app/Contents/MacOS/VoiceOverStarter"
else
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.VoiceOverTraining doNotShowSplashScreen -bool true && /System/Library/CoreServices/VoiceOver.app/Contents/MacOS/VoiceOverStarter"
end if
```

**Notes:**

Tested and works under **macOS Sierra**.

Comment: Thanks alot. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure following will work on macOS Sierra. Try yourself:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/VoiceOver.app/Contents/MacOS/VoiceOverStarter"
```

Comment: So, now it is clear. So my idea works on Mac OS Sierra too (and not **may then be a viable solution** as you say). It is enough to dismiiss the **VoiceOver Quick Start Guide** dialog on first launch. Although, the OP could have spoken out himself about my solution, and not be silent like a fish when they is offered help from another user than @user3439894. Of course, thank you for testings, upvote.

Comment: Something wasn't sitting right that it was opening the  **VoiceOver Quick Start Guide** the size of the screen and as if the **Learn More** button was pushed, so I spun up another occurrence of **macOS Sierra** and this does open up normally as if **⌘F5** had not yet been pushed or **VoiceOver** enabled thru **System Preferences**.  As I've deleted the previous occurrence of *macOS Sierra** I cannot investigate why I was getting the original results.

Comment: So this along with the additional code to check the **Do not show this message again** _checkbox_, if wanted, and then click the **Use ViceOver** _button_ will be the same as if having pressed **⌘F5** or enabling **VoiceOver** thru **System Preferences** for the first time. If the **Do not show this message again** _checkbox_ has already once been checked then this works as is. Sorry for any confusion.